# Multi-row horizontally centered list of floated items

Tags: html, css, css-float, alignment

I have a dynamically generated menu, which resides in resizable container. There are 4 requirements that I have to comply:

1. Items must form a horizontally centered menu.
2. They have to wrap into *n* amount of rows and remain aligned.
3. It must be an `<ul></ul>` list.
4. It must work with IE7+

Example:

```
>          Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4 | Item 5 | Item 6 | Item 7         <
```

Now, when container has shrunk down, itmes must form the following:

```
                  > Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4  <
                  >     | Item 5 | Item 6 | Item 7     <
```

The ***`<`*** and ***`>`*** signs represent container bounds.

How would I do that in HTML/CSS? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

I forgot to mention that I have to use `<ul>` and make it work under IE7+.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul id="container">
    <li class="item">Item1</li>
    <li class="item">Item2</li>
    <li class="item">Item3</li>
    <li class="item">Item4</li>
    <li class="item">Item5</li>
    <li class="item">Item6</li>
    <li class="item">Item7</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 8px;
    /* for ie7 */
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eqpGv/2/

Comment: Thanks! But i've forgot to say, that it hast to be an *ul* list.

Comment: Containers really don't matter, css is the same, but I updated the code and fiddle to be an unordered list.

Comment: Added hackery for new ie7 requirement.

Answer (score 1):

@Aleksandr

Just set the width of the div to your max preferred size, apply the style "text-align" to the div class & set it to "center", as your shell div grow's vertically the items will wrap & align center.

Comment: What about the child `<li>` items? What display type they have to be, inline? I have to make it work in IE 7 as well. And I forgot to mention, that this list has to be `<ul>`. I'll make an edit.